# The requested resource does not support http method 'GET" while making a POST call in WebAPI

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call an API written by me. However when I am trying to call a POST method via `$.ajax` it returns an error:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET"

When I try to call via Postman, I get the desired results. On top of this, the `$.ajax` for the same method works for all calls. Here is my API method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Ticket/GetTicketsAssignedToTechnician/")]        
public List<Ticket> GetTicketsAssignedToTechnician([FromBody]string technicianEmail)
{
    return dbManager.GetTicketsByAssignedTechnician(technicianEmail);
}
```

```
postData: function (serviceURL, parameterValue, success, failure, error) {
    $.ajax({
        url: serviceURL,
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(parameterValue),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: success,
        failure: failure,
        error: error
    });
}
```

Here is call to `$.ajax`:

```
Utility.postData(Dashboard.hostURL + "Ticket/GetTicketsAssignedToTechnician/", email, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}, function(data) {
  console.log("failure." + data.responseText);
}, function(data) {
  console.log("Error." + data.responseText);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using the wrong property name in the `$.ajax` options. it's `type`, not `method`. Therefore jQuery uses the default, which is `GET`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: serviceURL,
    type: "POST", // < change here
    data: parameterValue, // no need to JSON.stringify here, jQuery will do it for you
    // other options...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do as below

```
       $http({

            method: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(parameterValue),
            dataType: 'JSON'
        })
```